# Html Entity code for ž

Tags: html, character-encoding, special-characters

What is the HTML entity code for `ž`?

I am looking for something similar to `&raquo;` instead of something like `&#x17E;`.

Answer (score 12):

There is no [standard entity defined in HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html) to represent the character [`ž` (U+017E)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%BE); you can only use a numeric character reference like `&#x17E;` (hexadecimal) or `&#382;` (decimal).

But you can define such an entity for your document like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd" [
    <!ENTITY Zcaron  CDATA "&#381;"  -- latin capital letter Z with caron,
                                        U+017D ISOlat2 -->
    <!ENTITY zcaron  CDATA "&#382;"  -- latin small letter z with caron,
                                        U+017E ISOlat2 -->  
]>
```

Now you can reference the entities *Zcaron* (representing `&#381;`) and *zcaron* (representing `&#382;`) with `&Zcaron;` and `&zcaron;` respectively.

Or if you’re using a character set that contains that character (like Unicode’s character set), you can use a suitable character encoding (like UTF-8 in case of Unicode) to encode that character directly instead of using a character reference.

Comment: For reference, here are the HTML 4 character entities: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html

Answer (score 2):

```
&#382;
```

My favourite lookup tool is [LeftLogic's HTML Entity Character Lookup](http://leftlogic.com/lounge/articles/entity-lookup/) which allows you to find an entity based on visual similarity. In this case I typed in `z` and got entity and numeric codes for all variations of Latin z and Greek zeta.

Comment: I only got two characters, Latin z and Greek zeta. I don't see any variations.

Comment: @Kinopiko, you must check the option labeled "Incl. extended".

Answer (score 1):

`&#382;` It's easy to find [here at amp-what.com](http://amp-what.com/#q=z), along with about 100 other "Z"s. I have added quite a few extensions, to the LeftLogic codes, and evolved the searching.